# Find Articulation Points

Tags: graph-theory

I was reading some tutorials on finding articulation points in a graph and stumbled across this

1

> Carry out a depth-first search in G, starting from any node. Let T be
>   the tree generated by the depth-first search, and for each node v of
>   the graph, let prenum[v] be the number assigned by the search.

2

> Traverse the tree T in postorder. For each node v visited, calculate
>   lowest[v] as the minimum of prenum[v] prenum[w] for each node w such
>   that there exists an edge (v,w) in G that has no corresponding edge in
>   T. lowest[x] for every child x of v in T.

3

> Articulation points are
>   now determined as follows. The root of T is an articulation point of G
>   if and only if it has more than one child. A node v other than the
>   root of T is an articulation point G if and only if v has a child x
>   such that lowest[x] ≥ prenum[v].

[image]

but I don't really understand how to calculate lowest[x]. Can anyone make it a bit more clear?
Thank you!

Comment: “stumbled across this” where? Please give a link or cite the book or article.

Answer (score 1):

Step 2, in pseudo-code:

```
def visit(v):
    lowest[v] = prenum[v]
    for w in nodes:
        if v is the parent of w in T:
            visit(w)
            lowest[v] = min(lowest[v], lowest[w])
        elif w is connected to v in G:
            if w is not the parent of v in T:
                lowest[v] = min(lowest[v], prenum[w])
```

Answer (score 0):

An iterative pseudo-code version which combines steps 1 and 2:

```
i = 0
prenum[1] = lowest[1] = i = i + 1
S = EMPTY STACK

for each edge e connected to nodes[1]:
  push edge e onto S

while S is not empty:
  peek at edge e on S 
  let (u,v) = e such that prenum[u] <= prenum[v] or prenum[v] is undefined
  if e is unvisited
    mark e as visited
    if prenum[v] is undefined
      mark e as parent of v
      prenum[v] = lowest[v] = i = i + 1
      for each edge e' connected to nodes[v] except e:
        push edge e' onto S
    else
      pop e from S
      lowest[v] = min( lowest[v], prenum[u] )
  else
    pop e from S
    if e is marked as parent of v
      lowest[u] = min( lowest[u], [lowest[v] )
```